# Using an ODBC Data Source Name (DSN) in a connectionstring from OLEDB

Tags: vba, odbc, oledb, dsn

The following Excel VBA code runs fine:

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
With conn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = ";Data Source='" & _
        ThisWorkbook.FullName & _
        "';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';"
    .Open
    .Execute("select * from [ODBC;Driver={SQL Server};SERVER=MyServer\SqlInstance;DATABASE=DatabaseName;].dbo.Test")
End With
```

I have now added an ODBC Data Source Name to my machine and would like to use it but the following fails:

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
With conn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = ";Data Source='" & _
        ThisWorkbook.FullName & _
        "';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';"
    .Open
    .Execute("select * from [ODBC;Driver={SQL Server};DSN=MyDsn;].dbo.Test")
End With
```

The error message is "ODBC--connection to 'MyDsn' failed.".

Comment: have you tested the connection in the ODBC control panel?

Comment: If the ODBC control panel is the same as ODBC Data Source Adminitrator, yes I have. This is the output "TESTS COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY!"

Comment: it's a bit confusing - if you're connecting to SQL Server (either ODBC or via DSN), why is the `Data Source` in ConnnectionString being set to the workbook name, and the DSN is in the `SELECT` statement? Why not just put the DSN in the connection string?

Comment: This is because I'm also querying the workbook (admittedly, not in this particular query). I want to connect to SQL Server from within the query using both ODBC and DSN.